# Historical intraday dataset with penny stocks with a gap-up of 10% or above

Tags: equities, data, historical-data, intraday

I am trying to find intraday datasets of pennystocks. My criteria for the dataset is that it needs to only contain pennystocks where the gap-up was 10% or above.

I am looking for a free option but could not find any. I have also checked kaggle for datasets. I would also like to see paid plans, if that becomes my only option.

Another option would be to scrape for data, but this will be more time consuming.

Penny stock definition:

- Price between 0 and 5 USD
- Market cap between 0 and 300 million USD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often no pre-made dataset exists when you have such specific requirements. **Therefore, you have to find your own data by searching for penny-stocks that matches your criteria. This can be done via a stock-screener**. Doing a quick google search on "Gap-up stock screener" I found [this website](https://www.barchart.com/stocks/performance/gap/gap-up?viewName=main), where I sorted by highest percentage gap-up changes. From this, I found 4 stocks satisfying your criteria. I believe, this website gives gap-up events happened until a week prior, however, maybe there exist a different stock screener that can give you historical gap-up events?

**When you have found your pennystocks, you need to download your intraday data. This can be done on [Alphavantage.co](https://www.alphavantage.co/)**. You have to sign up for a free API key. Connecting to the API and downloading data via Python or R is well documented, and I encourage you to read the documentation. However, if you do not have any experience working in R or Python, you can download intraday data via a URL call also. Eg. downloading data in a .csv file on the pennystock Neostem Inc. (ticker: CLBS) can be done via the URL:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED&symbol=CLBS&interval=5min&slice=year1month1&apikey=YOUR_APIKEY_HERE

where you get the high, low, open, close prices in 5-minute increments. Also, replace "YOUR_APIKEY_HERE" with your API key. Remember that there is a limit to how much intraday data you can download at once (for 5 minute intervals, you can have a length max time-horizon of approximately one month).

Hopefully this helps.